# Using a Spring Data Rest @Projection as a representation for a resource in a custom controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

Is there any way to use a @Projection interface as the default representation for a resource in SDR? Either through the SDR repositories or through a custom controller?

It used to be possible in a custom controller to do this by injecting a `ProjectionFactory` and using the `createProjection` method, but this has been broken by a recent Spring Data Rest update.

I would like to enforce a particular view on an entity, and the SDR projections seem like an ideal method for doing this, especially in the context of a HAL API, as opposed to writing hard DTO classes for a custom controller and mapping between them etc. Excerpt projections are not what I am after, as these only apply when looking at an associated resource.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To answer my own question, there's now a couple of easyish ways to do this.

You can make SDR repository finders return projections by default:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Person,Long> {

    Set<PersonProjection> findByLastName(String lastName);

}
```

You can also selectively override responses that SDR would have handled for you by default by creating a custom Spring MVC controller with the @BasePathAwareController. You will need to inject the ProjectionFactory and possibly the PagedResourcesAssembler if you're planning on providing a paged response.

```
@BasePathAwareController
public class CustomPersonController {

@Autowired
private ProjectionFactory factory;

@Autowired
private PersonRepository personRepository;

@Autowired
private PagedResourcesAssembler<PersonProjection> assembler;

@RequestMapping(value="/persons", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/hal+json")
public ResponseEntity<?> getPeople(Pageable pageable) {
    Page<Person> people = personRepository.findAll(pageable);
    Page<PersonProjection> projected = people.map(l -> factory.createProjection(PersonProjection.class, l));
    PagedResources<Resource<PersonProjection>> resources = assembler.toResource(projected);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(resources);
}
```

Comment: In addittion to @adam respone, it is needed to add a `@Bean` in some `@Configuration` file e.g.

`@Configuration
  class SomeConfig {

  @Bean
  public SpelAwareProxyProjectionFactory projectionFactory() {
    return new SpelAwareProxyProjectionFactory();
  }
}`

[source](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29386907/3245552)

Answer (score 3):

I would like to suggest yet another solution.

I used custom controller as `@adam` suggested untill I had to `PATCH` a resource and get new representation back. There is no way to override `save` method of a repository to use a projection by default. Implementing custom controllers all the time brings some boilerplate into the project.

Since I already used `ResourceProcessor`s I decided to apply default projection right inside those processors.

```
@Component
public class ProductResourceProcessor implements ResourceProcessor<Resource<Product>> {

    @Autowired
    private ProjectionFactory projectionFactory;

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Resource<Product> process(Resource<Product> resource) {
        Product content = resource.getContent();
        ProductInline projection = projectionFactory.createProjection(ProductInline.class, content);
        Resource<ProductInline> result = new Resource<>(projection);
        //copying and adding links
        return (Resource) result;
    }
}
```

The processor repacks the content of processing resource. Thsi way the projection is applied no matter which handler returned the resource as a response (`GET`, `POST`, `PATCH` anything).

The drawback of this approach is it assumes that `spring-data-rest` doesn't require that the type of the content would be the same after processing. That may change anytime in the future releases.

Answer (score 2):

No it is not possible out of the box. Excerpt projections are always used if a resource is embedded. And on a single resource you can provide the desired projection as a query param.

What you can do is to use Jackson Mixins to change the json representation.

You can find some good examples here:
https://github.com/olivergierke/spring-restbucks/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springsource/restbucks/JacksonCustomizations.java

Comment: Thanks. Previously (pre-SDR 2.4.0), it was possible to just inject an instance of the `SpelAwareProxyProjectionFactory` into your controller class, and then in your custom controllers, call `createProjection` on the domain object you want projected, and then return the projection in the response, but this has since unfortunately been broken by one or more changes on the SDR side. the Jackson Mixins route is much more involved and clunkier.

Comment: There was similar question before and Oliver Gierke directly anwered it with some nice argumentation why it is not a good idea to use projections for single resources - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30220333/why-is-an-excerpt-projection-not-applied-automatically-for-a-spring-data-rest-it

Comment: Yeah, I saw that, though that was mostly related to excerpts and using the standard SDR exported repositories. Though, Oliver also outlined how to do exactly what I am after (and what I was doing) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29376090/how-to-apply-spring-data-projections-in-a-spring-mvc-controllers/29386907#29386907 and here: https://spring.io/blog/2015/03/26/what-s-new-in-spring-data-fowler but these code samples no longer work in the current version of SDR, throwing a Jackson exception.